# An entity is a part of another, what would this larger entity be called from the other's perspective?

Tags: single-word-requests

A is part of B, that would make B A's _____? What's an appropriate word to use here? A is a constituent of B, but what is B relative to A?

The question arose from naming a variable in programming. I have a scene that contains objects that the scene can contain. So these objects would be constituents/parts/... of the scene. But the the objects are to contain a variable referencing the scene, as that'd be useful. I don't want to name it just "scene", because that's no fun :P . So what to name this variable is really what I'm after, but it'd be nice to know if there's a neat word I can use in future situations like this.

Comment: In the context of computer programming, this is commonly called the "parent".

Comment: For the sake of your team, go with Scene. Or at least, when someone comes along with an answer you like, name the variable object.ContainingScene or whatever. Object.Container would be difficult to discover. :)

Comment: I thought about that, but would prefer another word since I'm already using the parent-child terminology between objects in relating their transforms. Feels like I'm being overly pedantic though, "parentScene" and "parentSceneObject" shouldn't confuse anyone. Still curious about such a word outside of programming though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site? Container? Owner? Parent? Context?